# How to access private azure blob storage file from application?

Tags: c#, reactjs, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am using azure blob storage to keep my file. azure storage container is private. I have to access **html** file from private blob. I am able get the html file Stream object using c#, by that I can access html file content. But html file is not loading css/js/image files which is using inside html file.
css/js file reside in same private container. How can I load html file with all js/css/image files?

**Note:**
Loading html inside iframe.

Comment: My blob container is private, I can access html file but related css/js files are not loading which is used inside html file and reside in same container.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Community, attaching a html which is reside in private container, and in same container css/js file reside used inside html file.  Able to download file using c# container and connection string, but css/js/image  files are not applied in html which is used in html.

<html><head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>TEST </title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="a.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/vd.css">
    
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
    Hello world
    <script type="text/javascript" src="styles/abc.js"></script>
</body></html>

Answer (score 0):

> But html file is not loading css/js files which is using inside html
> file. css/js file reside in same private container. How can I load
> html file with all js/css files?

Simple answer is you cannot. For blobs inside a private blob container, request to get those blobs must be [authorized](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-requests-to-azure-storage).

One possible solution would be to keep these CSS/JS files in a separate container and set its ACL as either `Blob` or `Container`.